# displaying multiple divs columns within a list item on mobile

Tags: css, html

Im building a football app (using phonegap, backbone, require and topcoat.io) allowing users to pick their man of the match (MOTD).

In the MOTD template, I want to display the player name, position, a link to their full external profile and a radio button. The HTML looks like:

```
<li class="topcoat-list__item">

    <div class="player-container">

        <div class="player-details">
        <label for="player_516" class="topcoat-radio-button">
            <input type="radio" name="player_id" id="player_516" value="516">

            <p>Robin van Persie</p>
            <p>Forward</p>
       </label>
        </div>

        <div class="player-more">
            <a target="_blank" href="http://www.premierleague.com//en-gb/players/profile.overview.html/robin-van-persie">More</a>
        </div>            

    </div>  
</li>
```

The CSS is:

```
.player-more{
    width:48%;
    float:left;
}

.player-details{
    vertical-align: middle;
    float:left;
    width:48%;
}
```

But it comes out looking like so on a mobile:

[list example http://match.webintelligence.ie/img/motm.png](http://match.webintelligence.ie/img/motm.png)

Maybe I'm trying to include too much information in each list item. Any suggestions as to how I could present this better? Maybe I dont need the radio buttons. Instead, if a user clicks anywhere on the list, it will highlight it and this will be their selection. Except if the click "more", in which case the external link will show...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your `p` elements are block-level elements. This means they will occupy their own line. Change the `p` to an inline element.

```
p.player-name {
  display: inline;
}
```

Or use a `span` element, which is `inline` by default.